# Running total sum of one list, stored in a new list - python

Tags: python, list, sum

I have the following list:

```
myList = [5,15,23,45,2,43]
```

I want to create a running total in a new list, so it would look like:

```
newList = [20,43,88,90,133]
```

How would I do this?

Comment: `np.cumsum(myLlist)[1:]`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
newList = [sum(myList[:i+1]) for i in range(len(myList))][1:]
```